# Strange Grid Behavior with PyPlot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I recently started messing with PyPlot, and I am seeing some strange behavior with the grid properties.  Namely, that one of my major grid lines is the wrong color:
[image: PyPlot Curve - notice the gray major grid line at 0.06]
Here is my code for stylizing the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

aX = np.array([4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24])           # x-axis
aY = np.array([1,4,10,20,35,56,80,104,125,140,146,140,125,104,80,56,35,20,10,4,1])  # y-axis
aY = aY / aY.sum()

plt.plot(aX, aY)                                                                    # plot curve and show

plt.xlim((0, 30))
plt.ylim(ymin = 0)
plt.grid(True, 'major', color='k')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(True, 'minor', 'y')
plt.show()
```

the line `plt.grid(True, 'major', color='k')` line should set the major grid lines to black, but the line at 0.06 is clearly gray.  Any ideas what could be causing this?  Is it just a weird behavioral issue on my end?

Thanks.

Comment: That's clealy unexpected. However, can you please make this reproducible for others, [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry, edited the code section.  Note that I've left the curve-smoothing out.  Oddly, I've noticed that if I comment out `aY = aY / aY.sum()` the issue goes away.

Comment: If you set the ylimits differently, you can even get all lines gray, `plt.ylim(-0.014, 0.12)`. For some reason a gray line is placed directly above the black line (which is there, just hidden behind the gray one). This is clearly a bug in matplotlib. Do you want to open an issue about it at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues ?

Comment: When I look really close, I can see the black line there.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I will open an issue, as suggested.  in the mean time, I will just live with it.  Thanks for verifying!

Comment: As this is a library issue, I am voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug in a library, not in the code itself.

Comment: Why? Any answer to this may enlighten us on the reason for this and to a possible fix. No reason to close this.

Comment: That is fair.  I seem to remember being told a similar question was off-topic in the past, but I could be mistaken.  Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess it would be off topic for a closed-source library. But matplotlib is open-source; it is hence a problem everyone has access to and can potentially solve. xref: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11758

Comment: That is a good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug due to overlaying minor/major grids. It has been fixed in newer versions of matplotlib (see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11758#issuecomment-407243033) for information about the fix).

Thanks to ImportanceOfBeingErnest for suggesting I post a bug and helping to drive the fix.